# The fan won't slow down on my Dell Optiplex 760

Tags: fan, slackware

I have a new ***Optiplex*** 760 running ***Slackware*** v13 (x64).  The power supply fan comes full on when I turn on the box and never slows down.  I'm expect it to slow down after it senses the load/heat, but it never does.

This PC runs the latest Intel chipset (1Ch10).

I've loaded the kubuntu 9.04 live cd and had the same problem.  Could there be a bad sensor some where or do I have a config problem.

\\Greg

Comment: Have you checked whether there is a BIOS upgrade available that could address this?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to check.  I upgraded the BIOS about 45 days ago and verified tonight that it is the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got good news and bad news...  The good news is you're not the only person having problems with Dell PSU fans and THERE IS A FIX.  We recently purchased a few dozen Dell 760s and three of them had loud (high RPM) PSU fans.  The bad news is Dell had to send a tech to replace all the PSUs with this problem.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed, a year later I swapped out the power supply and it got better :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the BIOS for fan settings?
Try looking for BIOS upgrades and giving the fan a good clean.

Some BIOS settings can change the speed of the fan dependant on the heat of the temperature. I had a similar issue with an extremely loud south bridge fan that clunked - it ran up to 4000 RPM when >40deg C - and it usually run at 42deg C. A quick change of the BIOS to only rack up to said speed at 45deg C and it was no longer an issue.

Comment: There is a BIOS setting for FAN Override, but I've verified that it is off (with it on the CPU fan really got moving!)

To clarify, thi sis the powersupply fan.  I tried swapping out the power supply to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Check for bios upgrades and known acpi issues.

Comment: BIOS is verified latest.  How do I find acpi issues?

Answer (score 0):

get a hoover and hoover out the dust. that should slow it down ;-)

Comment: Beware static electricity that vacuums can generate!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build a new kernel with some ACPI BIOS settings enabled. I used to have the same problem running Slackware 11-12 on my desktop.